# Merge On Doesn't Work, But Merge Inner Does Work. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames, which look like this.

```
grouped_and_summed.columns
Out[173]: 
Index(['IDRSSD_ID', 'Call_Report_Schedule_Code', '2001Q1', '2001Q2', '2001Q3',
       '2001Q4', '2002Q1', '2002Q2', '2002Q3', '2002Q4', '2003Q1', '2003Q2',
       '2003Q3', '2003Q4', '2004Q1', '2004Q2', '2004Q3', '2004Q4', '2005Q1',
       '2005Q2', '2005Q3', '2005Q4', '2006Q1', '2006Q2', '2006Q3', '2006Q4',
       '2007Q1', '2007Q2', '2007Q3', '2007Q4', '2008Q1', '2008Q2', '2008Q3',
       '2008Q4', '2009Q1', '2009Q2', '2009Q3', '2009Q4', '2010Q1', '2010Q2',
       '2010Q3', '2010Q4', '2011Q1', '2011Q2', '2011Q3', '2011Q4', '2012Q1',
       '2012Q2', '2012Q3', '2012Q4', '2013Q1', '2013Q2', '2013Q3', '2013Q4',
       '2014Q1', '2014Q2', '2014Q3', '2014Q4', '2015Q1', '2015Q2', '2015Q3',
       '2015Q4', '2016Q1', '2016Q2', '2016Q3', '2016Q4', '2017Q1', '2017Q2',
       '2017Q3', '2017Q4', '2018Q1', '2018Q2', '2018Q3', '2018Q4', '2019Q4'],
      dtype='object', name='qyear')

df_list.columns
Out[174]: Index(['IDRSSD_ID', 'Line_Item'], dtype='object')
```

Both have matching `'IDRSSD_ID'` in each index.

I figured the following line of code should work, but it does not. #1

```
df_final = pd.merge(grouped_and_summed, df_list, on='IDRSSD_ID')
```

It gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-178-5a5a7ffc608a>", line 1, in <module>
    df_final = pd.merge(grouped_and_summed, df_list, on='IDRSSD_ID')

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 87, in merge
    validate=validate,

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 652, in __init__
    ) = self._get_merge_keys()

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 1018, in _get_merge_keys
    left_keys.append(left._get_label_or_level_values(lk))

  File "C:\Users\ryans\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1563, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: 'IDRSSD_ID'
```

Similarly, this line of code does not work: #2

```
df_final = pd.merge(grouped_and_summed, df_list, how="inner", on=["IDRSSD_ID", "IDRSSD_ID"])
```

This following line of code works just fine. #3

```
df_final = pd.merge(grouped_and_summed, df_list, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')
```

I'm fine using methodology #3, and refraining from using #1 or #2, but I'm curious to know why #1 and #2 do not work.  When I read the documentation form the lik below, it seems like all three methodologies should work just fine.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: They look the same, but I'd do `grouped_and_summed.columns = grouped_and_summed.columns.str.strip()` and `df_list.columns = df_list.columns.str.strip()` and then try the merge, just to be sure.

Comment: Why does `group_and_summed.columns` have a `name` ?

Comment: Maybe it is multiindex with `qyear` and something else?